# Removing data existing in a closed brackets

Tags: qgis, regular-expression

I have a dataset that contains a number of closed brackets with data. I don't want the data which exists in the brackets. How can I remove that in QGIS?

Mcdonalds(Park Avenue)
KFC (Park Avenue) Restaurant
(Financial District) Hotel Marriot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this expression, where `name` is the name of the input attribute field:

```
regexp_replace ("name", '\\(.+\\)','')
```

If you also want to avoid any whitspaces (space etc.) at the beginning or end of the text field, e.g. resulting from deleting a bracket at the beginning (like your 3rd example), add a [`trim()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#trim) function:

```
trim (regexp_replace ("name", '\\(.+\\)',''))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The challenge with removing what is between the parentheses with `regex_replace` is that one can end up with multiple spaces between the two parts, e.g., "KFC⎵(Park⎵Avenue)⎵Restaurant" getting replaced with "KFC⎵⎵Restaurant".  Whereas `trim` addresses additional spaces at the start and end of the string, it doesn't address additional spaces in the middle of the string.

Sticking with `regex_replace` and removing the parenthetical content, one can replace the parenthetical content with an empty string and then split the string apart and re-assemble it to remove extra spaces.  `array_filter` is needed so that spaces and empty strings from splitting do not get re-inserted as spaces into the new string.

```
array_to_string(
  array_filter(
    string_to_array(
      regexp_replace("name", '\\(.*\\)',''),
      ' '
    ),
    @element
  ),
  ' '
)
```

Using [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](https://regexr.com/) to explain this regular expression:

> \( **Escaped character**. Matches a "(" character (char code 40).
> . **Dot**. Matches any character except line breaks.
>    * **Quantifier**. Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
> \) **Escaped character**. Matches a ")" character (char code 41).

As opposed to removing what is between the parentheses, one can take the approach of identifying what exists before and after the parentheses using `regex_matches` and building a new string from those elements while ignoring what is between the parentheses.

```
array_to_string(
  array_filter(
    regexp_matches(
      "name",
      '^\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\(.*\\)\\s*(.*?)\\s*$'
    ),
    @element
  ),
  ' '
)
```

Using [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](https://regexr.com/) to explain this regular expression:

> ^ **Beginning.** Matches the beginning of the string, or the beginning
> of a line if the multiline flag (m) is enabled.
> \s **Whitespace.** Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).
>   * **Quantifier.** Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
> ( **Capturing group #1.** Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture
> group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.
>   . **Dot.** Matches any character except line breaks.
>     * **Quantifier.** Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
>       ? **Lazy.** Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible.
> )
> \s **Whitespace.** Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).
>   * **Quantifer.** Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
> \( **Escaped character.** Matches a "(" character (char code 40).
> . **Dot.** Matches any character except line breaks.
>   * **Quantifer.** Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
> \) **Escaped character.** Matches a ")" character (char code 41).
> ( **Capturing group #2.** Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.
>   . **Dot.** Matches any character except line breaks.
>     * **Quantifier.** Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
>       ? **Lazy.** Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible.
> )
> \s **Whitespace.** Matches any whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks).
>   * **Quantifer.** Match 0 or more of the preceding token.
> $ **End.** Matches the end of the string, or the end of a line if multilline flag (m) is enabled.